# срабатывание hover на блоке из множества однотипных блоков vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jade, pug, бэм

Есть 9 одинаковых блоков. Нужно чтобы при наводке на блок, подсвечивался hover этого блока. Сейчас срабатывает hover для всех сразу блоков, как исправить это?

```
 v-flex(xs12='', sm6='' mt-3='').top-posts-container
            h2 Топ 9 изображений
            +b.V-FLEX(xs12='', sm12='').top-posts
              +b(v-for="item in topPhoto"  @mouseover="display = true" @mouseout="display.hover = false").top-posts__post
                  +e.A(:href="item.pic_url")
                    img(:src="item.pic_url" ).top-posts__post__image
                  +b.top-posts__post__shadow(:class="item.hover ? 'shadow-visible' : ''")
```

Данные с сервера в формате:

```
 {
    "id": 1410,
    "full_name": "Broderick Thompson",
    "follower_count": 632,
    "pic_url": "https://instagram.fhen2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a17a8ceee608ce59a67c018dc3cb3b08/5C14138F/t51.2885-19/s320x320/23734392_2031019543847816_5890479768800854016_n.jpg"
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй модификатор события stop или self, например: `@mouseover.stop=""`

[Подробнее](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9)